# How to log user's leave and join time to a voice channel in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey guys I'm writing a discord bot and I want to log when a user enters and leaves a voice channel. But apparently, I'm a little confused right now. Do you guys have any ideas on how can I use the `on_voice_state_update()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update).

It takes in two arguments `before` and `after`, so to check if someone left, just compare `before` and `after`, and if it's not the same, you can log it in some file (maybe `json` or `pickle` or `sqlite` libraries can help with this)

I provide some quick sample code below:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: 
        print("difference")
```

We observe a few things: first, `before` and `after` are `VoiceState` objects, you can view their attributes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState), that's how I get the `before.channel` and so on.

Second, `client` is whatever you named your bot (i.e. `client = commands.Bot(..)`)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    ...
```

docs: [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)